# How can i add a form in each row in HTML datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have an ordinary table generated with Ajax sourced data, it looks like this:

**Ajax**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "myurl",
        "dataType": 'json',
        "dataSrc": '',

        "columns": [
          {"data": "item"},
          {"data": "status"},
          {"data": "price"},
      ]

    } );
} );
</script>
```

**Html**

```
 <table id="mytable" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>ITEM</th>
          <th>STATUS</th>
          <th>PRICE</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I would like to add a new column to this table, basically each row should have a form that, when hit, will fire an Ajax request containing the value of the field `Status`, so i should have:

```
<th>ITEM</th>
<th>STATUS</th>
<th>PRICE</th>
<th>BUTTON</th>
```

Here is my form:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myform").submit(function (event) {
        callAJAX( "myurl/",
         {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
         parameters={'status': $('status').val()},

        'post',
         function(data){
          console.log('submitted')


         }, null, null );
 return false; 
  });

});
</script>



<form method='post' id='myform'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" id="status"/>
  <button name="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SEND</button>
</form>
```

So, each row has four fields: `item`, `status`, `price`, `button`. On every row there is a button below the column `button`. When the button on a row is hit, ajax should send a post request with the value of `status` for that particular row. Is there any way to do it? The biggest problem here is adding the form to Datatable, i did not find much about how to do it. Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a form if you're submitted the value via AJAX.  You can add an event handler to capture the button click event, and then send the value via AJAX.  You know that the value you want to send is in the same row as the button that was clicked.  You can traverse the DOM to get the value, or, just add the value as a data attribute to the button when you're building out the rows of the DataTable.

```
$('#mytable').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "myurl",
    "dataType": 'json',
    "dataSrc": '',

    "columns": [
      {"data": "item"},
      {"data": "status"},
      {"data": "price"},
      {"data": "status"}
  ],
  "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [3],
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<button type="button" class="btnClick" data-status="replace">Send</button>'.replace("replace", data);
                }
            }
        ]
} );
```

So, with the code above, I've added a 4th column that holds the Status value, and that value is rendered as a data attribute on a button.  I also added a class so that it's easy to bind a click event:

```
$(document).on('click','.btnClick', function() {
   var statusVal = $(this).data("status");
   console.log(statusVal);
   //do the AJAX call...
});
```

[Here is a Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/h143f7qe/9/)
(You'll notice that I had to adjust data source for the DataTable for the purpose of the example)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, this is truly great. I can see the send button appearing, the only problem is that nothing happens when i hit it. I tried to look into my console but there is no error popping there. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: @Jack022 - Sounds like the jQuery event isn't firing.  If you inspect the HTML of a button, is it structured correctly?  Is it rendering with the data attribute?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be structured correctly, i'm trying to see what's wrong!

Comment: Yeah, the event is not firing. I tried adding a dummy console.log() inside the success function but it doesn't work

Comment: @Jack022 - I updated my answer and added a link to a Fiddle demo.  You'll see that it console logs the status based on the clicked-on button.

Comment: I'm sorry @devlin, so basically i was already messing with my console before opening this question, so i had to filter the results of my console.log to a certain part of the page, this is why i was not seeing the event firing, my bad :)

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for your help. Just one last thing, could you please explain  what does the attribute "targets" do? And what is data-status in the html?

Comment: @Jack022 - "targets" identifies which column in the DataTable the render should apply to.  It's zero based, so the first column is 0, and the 4th column is 3.  So, we're saying the render should apply to the 4th column.  "data-status" is known as a data attribute.  It allows you to store custom attributes & values on an HTML element without violating HTML standards.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!